# bash script to git pull

Tags: git, bash

So I have several folders for a list of subdomains. Each folder contains the same script which dynamically guesses the host and loads several configs.

So the list is growing and cd to each folder to git pull is becoming a boring task.

My client's hosting service is limited and I cannot add a ssh key to the host in order for the pull to be "passwordless", so I make the pull via HTTPS.

Im not a bash expert but the basic loop would be:

```
for dir in /tmp/*/
do
 #passwordless pulls
done
```

Now here is the catch, some folders needs to pull develop and others pull master branch.

Comment: When you say "some folders needs to pull develop and others pull master", will it always be the branch they're already on, or at least its upstream? i.e. Will a simple `git pull` do?

Answer (score 3):

```
while read repo remote branch rest; do
   (  cd $repo
      git pull $remote $branch
      # do whatever with $rest 
   ) 2>&1 | sed "s#^#$repo: #" &
done <<EOD
/path/to/repo origin branch1
/path/to/another github master
EOD
```

Or you could put the stuff in a file and `</path/to/file` instead of inlining it after `<<EOD`.

This will fire off all the pulls in parallel, if you have lots of them perhaps it'd be better to replace the `&` at the end with a `;` (or equivalently here remove it).

Comment: You lack the final delimiter in the `sed` substitution.  You cannot use slash as the delimiter if you interpolate strings containing (unescaped) slashes into the script.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing terminator.  I don't think I've ever heard of anybody adding a remote name with a slash in it, but if anybody ever does sed accepts any character as a separator, `^` would probably be good, or a control character like `^A`.

Comment: Uh, you are interpolating `$repo` into the `sed` script, which has slashes in your example.  `| sed "s%^%$repo: %"`

Answer (score 1):

```
DEVLIST="list of hosts that pull develop"
MASTERLIST="list of hosts that pull master"

for D in ${DEVLIST}
do
  cd /tmp/${D}
  git clone https://my.repo.edu/git/repo.git -b develop --single-branch
done

for M in ${MASTERLIST}
do
  cd /tmp/${M}
  git clone https://my.repo.edu/git/repo.git -b master --single-branch
done
```